# react two json object merge and result: empty slots

Tags: reactjs, object

I have 2 json objects (covidResults and infoResults) and I want to merge them if codcentre are the same in both objects. I want to get the result like this (finalResults), where:
*totalSchoolsByRegion: is the total of schools in concatResults* and *totalCovidRegion: are the number of schools in each region that their condition estat==='Confinat'*

```
finalResults = {
{codeRegion: "01", regionName: "Baix Empordà", totalSchoolsByRegion: 2, totalCovidRegion: 0},
{codeRegion: "02", regionName: "Alt Empordà", totalSchoolsByRegion: 2, totalCovidRegion: 1},
{codeRegion: "03", regionName: "Alta Ribagorça", totalSchoolsByRegion: 3, totalCovidRegion: 2},
```

But in newObjectResults i have **empty slots**, and I can get all the information, because I have undefined results

MY CODE

```
const covidResults = [
  { datageneracio: "2020-09-23T00:00:00.000",
    codcentre: "17010402",
    estat: "Obert",
    grup_confin: "0",
    alumn_confin: "0",
    docent_confin: "0",
    altres_confin: "0"
  },
  { datageneracio: "2020-09-23T00:00:00.000",
    codcentre: "17010384",
    estat: "Obert",
    grup_confin: "0",
    alumn_confin: "0",
    docent_confin: "0",
    altres_confin: "0"
  },
  { datageneracio: "2020-09-23T00:00:00.000",
    codcentre: "17008948",
    estat: "Confinat",
    grup_confin: "0",
    alumn_confin: "0",
    docent_confin: "0",
    altres_confin: "0"
  },
  {
    datageneracio: "2020-09-23T00:00:00.000",
    codcentre: "17008900",
    estat: "Obert",
    grup_confin: "0",
    alumn_confin: "0",
    docent_confin: "0",
    altres_confin: "0"
  },
  { datageneracio: "2020-09-23T00:00:00.000",
    codcentre: "8000131",
    estat: "Confinat",
    grup_confin: "0",
    alumn_confin: "0",
    docent_confin: "0",
    altres_confin: "0"
  },
  { datageneracio: "2020-09-23T00:00:00.000",
    codcentre: "8000153",
    estat: "Obert",
    grup_confin: "0",
    alumn_confin: "0",
    docent_confin: "0",
    altres_confin: "0"
  },
  { datageneracio: "2020-09-23T00:00:00.000",
    codcentre: "8000165",
    estat: "Confinat",
    grup_confin: "0",
    alumn_confin: "0",
    docent_confin: "0",
    altres_confin: "0"
  }
];

const infoResults = [
  { codcentre: "17010402",
    name: "Llar d'infants Municipal La Bòbila",
    address: "av. de Can Caramany, s/n",
    codi_postal: "17121",
    regionName: "Baix Empordà",
    codeRegion: "10",
    city: "Corçà",
    long: "3.014146876",
    lat: "41.98864073"
  },
  { codcentre: "17010384",
    name: "L'Energia-C.aut.ens.art.pro.de Música Palafrugell",
    address: "Pi i Margall,114/Manufactur.Suro,51-67",
    codi_postal: "17200",
    regionName: "Baix Empordà",
    codeRegion: "10",
    city: "Palafrugell",
    long: "3.164713218",
    lat: "41.921198948"
  },
  { codcentre: "17008948",
    name: "Llar d'infants Els Nins",
    address: "pl. Onze de Setembre, 1",
    codi_postal: "17493",
    regionName: "Alt Empordà",
    codeRegion: "02",
    city: "Vilajuïga",
    long: "3.094177279",
    lat: "42.327433814"
  },
  { codcentre: "17008900",
    name: "Llar d'infants de Cabanes",
    address: "c. Colon, 8",
    codi_postal: "17761",
    regionName: "Alt Empordà",
    codeRegion: "02",
    city: "Cabanes",
    long: "2.977203057",
    lat: "42.30876845"
  },
  { codcentre: "08000131",
    name: "La Presentació",
    address: "c. Pompeu Fabra, 2",
    codi_postal: "08350",
    regionName: "Maresme",
    codeRegion: "21",
    city: "Arenys de Mar",
    long: "2.547075835",
    lat: "41.585754015"
  },
  { codcentre: "08000153",
    name: "Escola Joan Maragall",
    address: "c. Riera Sa Clavella, s/n",
    codi_postal: "08350",
    regionName: "Maresme",
    codeRegion: "21",
    city: "Arenys de Mar",
    long: "2.54631495",
    lat: "41.582404768"
  },
  {
    codcentre: "08000165",
    name: "Escola Sant Martí",
    address: "c. Generalitat, 2",
    codi_postal: "08358",
    regionName: "Maresme",
    codeRegion: "21",
    city: "Arenys de Munt",
    long: "2.53853995",
    lat: "41.609034581"
  }
];
let concatResults = [];
    covidResults.forEach(function (item) {
      return infoResults.map(school => {
        if (infoResults !== undefined && school.codcentre === item.codcentre) {
          concatResults.push({
            estat: item.estat,
            codecentre: item.codcentre,
            regionName: school.regionName,
            codeRegion: school.codeRegion,
            name: school.name
          });
        }
      });
    });

    let newObjectResults = [];
    concatResults.forEach(item => {
      if (!newObjectResults.hasOwnProperty(item.codeRegion)) {
        newObjectResults[item.codeRegion] = {
          codeRegion: item.codeRegion,
          regionName: item.regionName,
          schools: []
        };
      }
      newObjectResults[item.codeRegion].schools.push({
        codecentre: item.codecentre,
        estat: item.estat
      });
    });
console.log("newObjectResults", newObjectResults);

    let finalResults = [];
    let totalCovidRegion = 0;
    newObjectResults.map(item => {
      if (item !== undefined) {
        finalResults.push({
          codeRegion: item.codeRegion,
          regionName: item.regionName,
          totalSchoolsByRegion: item.schools.length,
          totalCovidRegion
        });
        item.schools.map(it => {
          if (it.estat === "Confinat") {
            totalCovidRegion += 1;
          }
        });
      }
    });

    console.log("finalResults", finalResults);
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ccvccv/f0sx1ugz/14/#&togetherjs=8Oa7rHjpGq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to use loops to do this and your undefined is cause by unmatching codcentre which starts with 0 so i did a parseInt before comparing.

You can do a map and reduce which would give you the expected results like below.

```js
const covidResults = [{
    datageneracio: "2020-09-23T00:00:00.000",
    codcentre: "17010402",
    estat: "Obert",
    grup_confin: "0",
    alumn_confin: "0",
    docent_confin: "0",
    altres_confin: "0"
  },
  {
    datageneracio: "2020-09-23T00:00:00.000",
    codcentre: "17010384",
    estat: "Obert",
    grup_confin: "0",
    alumn_confin: "0",
    docent_confin: "0",
    altres_confin: "0"
  },
  {
    datageneracio: "2020-09-23T00:00:00.000",
    codcentre: "17008948",
    estat: "Confinat",
    grup_confin: "0",
    alumn_confin: "0",
    docent_confin: "0",
    altres_confin: "0"
  },
  {
    datageneracio: "2020-09-23T00:00:00.000",
    codcentre: "17008900",
    estat: "Obert",
    grup_confin: "0",
    alumn_confin: "0",
    docent_confin: "0",
    altres_confin: "0"
  },
  {
    datageneracio: "2020-09-23T00:00:00.000",
    codcentre: "8000131",
    estat: "Confinat",
    grup_confin: "0",
    alumn_confin: "0",
    docent_confin: "0",
    altres_confin: "0"
  },
  {
    datageneracio: "2020-09-23T00:00:00.000",
    codcentre: "8000153",
    estat: "Obert",
    grup_confin: "0",
    alumn_confin: "0",
    docent_confin: "0",
    altres_confin: "0"
  },
  {
    datageneracio: "2020-09-23T00:00:00.000",
    codcentre: "8000165",
    estat: "Confinat",
    grup_confin: "0",
    alumn_confin: "0",
    docent_confin: "0",
    altres_confin: "0"
  }
];

const infoResults = [{
    codcentre: "17010402",
    name: "Llar d'infants Municipal La Bòbila",
    address: "av. de Can Caramany, s/n",
    codi_postal: "17121",
    regionName: "Baix Empordà",
    codeRegion: "10",
    city: "Corçà",
    long: "3.014146876",
    lat: "41.98864073"
  },
  {
    codcentre: "17010384",
    name: "L'Energia-C.aut.ens.art.pro.de Música Palafrugell",
    address: "Pi i Margall,114/Manufactur.Suro,51-67",
    codi_postal: "17200",
    regionName: "Baix Empordà",
    codeRegion: "10",
    city: "Palafrugell",
    long: "3.164713218",
    lat: "41.921198948"
  },
  {
    codcentre: "17008948",
    name: "Llar d'infants Els Nins",
    address: "pl. Onze de Setembre, 1",
    codi_postal: "17493",
    regionName: "Alt Empordà",
    codeRegion: "02",
    city: "Vilajuïga",
    long: "3.094177279",
    lat: "42.327433814"
  },
  {
    codcentre: "17008900",
    name: "Llar d'infants de Cabanes",
    address: "c. Colon, 8",
    codi_postal: "17761",
    regionName: "Alt Empordà",
    codeRegion: "02",
    city: "Cabanes",
    long: "2.977203057",
    lat: "42.30876845"
  },
  {
    codcentre: "08000131",
    name: "La Presentació",
    address: "c. Pompeu Fabra, 2",
    codi_postal: "08350",
    regionName: "Maresme",
    codeRegion: "21",
    city: "Arenys de Mar",
    long: "2.547075835",
    lat: "41.585754015"
  },
  {
    codcentre: "08000153",
    name: "Escola Joan Maragall",
    address: "c. Riera Sa Clavella, s/n",
    codi_postal: "08350",
    regionName: "Maresme",
    codeRegion: "21",
    city: "Arenys de Mar",
    long: "2.54631495",
    lat: "41.582404768"
  },
  {
    codcentre: "08000165",
    name: "Escola Sant Martí",
    address: "c. Generalitat, 2",
    codi_postal: "08358",
    regionName: "Maresme",
    codeRegion: "21",
    city: "Arenys de Munt",
    long: "2.53853995",
    lat: "41.609034581"
  }
];



const tempResults = covidResults.map(x => {
  const y = infoResults.find(y => parseInt(y.codcentre) === parseInt(x.codcentre));
  return { ...x,
    ...y
  };
});

const output = tempResults.reduce((a, c) => {

  const item = a.find(x => x.codeRegion === c.codeRegion);
  if (item) {
    item.totalSchoolsByRegion++;
    item.totalCovidRegion += (c.estat === 'Confinat' ? 1 : 0)
  } else {
    a.push({
      codeRegion: c.codeRegion,
      regionName: c.regionName,
      totalSchoolsByRegion: 1,
      totalCovidRegion: c.estat === 'Confinat' ? 1 : 0
    });
  }

  return a;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```